# Recreation District Trails to public Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, kml

I have created a kml of over 30 trails with trailheads that my team and I GPS'd throughout the past couple of years for our local recreation district ([Brooktrails Redwood Forest][1]). We have a trail map that has been printed and is being used by our county residents and visitors, however, when they look for recreation trails (foot and bike), none of the District trails are visible in GoogleMaps. Is there a way to import all of these rather than having to draw the trails within Google Maps? They are also accessible via Google My Maps - but that's not particularly useful for people who are searching from outside the circle with whom I've shared the link. I've also contacted MapMy...everything and in order to create routes using trails, the trails have to be on GoogleMaps. I suspect this is the case for all run/ride tracking apps. So... again, is there a way to import a kml of the 30+ trails and trailheads to GoogleMaps? Drawing each is a daunting task as they are all over a mile long through varying terrain - plus the accuracy decreases significantly. In case the link in BRF doesn't work, here is the link to Google MyMaps: https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/edit?mid=1GcKhd2rPOCBtSqoH8KyzdBVI_V7zzhxB&ll=39.43926886661395%2C-123.40566300000002&z=13
I appreciate the help. If we can get the trails in GoogleMaps, then other opportunities open for us in terms of trail maintenance/care, grants, and usability for locals and visitors alike.
Crystal